How to blend two RGB colours?
I have a C# application where I have a number of locations and each location has a number of nodes. I ping each location and if it responds it's GREEN, the shade of GREEN depends on the response time; the shorter the response the greener the colour.
If no response to the ping is received then the colour will be RED.
Based on a number of nodes for each location and different possible colours for each node, I want to come up with a colour for the location which is derived from all the child node colours, a blend of its child node colours.
How could I do this?
The control is a TreeView.

How about an average of the RGB values ?

You could just take the average of each of the R, G and B values. I'm not sure it would be very nice if some are red and others green, though.

@PalleDue, its not really a question of what's nice, the point is to raise the operators attention to the fact it isn't green and therefore expand the location to investigate.

It's normally nicer to work with HSV rather than RGB when blending colours. Averaging red and green takes you through yellow, which might be a nice feature. Grab a colour editor which has sliders for H, S and V, and have a play. You might be able to come up with colours where you keep S and V the same and just move H around, and the colours you get as you move H are all nice and sensible -- that would be easy to implement in code

I would be very careful with this. Blending of colors could easily hide information and make identification much more difficult. You might for example want to easily identify if a location has one or more red nodes. Not to mention color blindness. For any critical information you want to use both color and shape.

@JonasH, I’ve been thinking about that and will add an indicator/led to the left of the text and use the colours on that, could use a square LED for not responding red and round LED green for healthy

Seeing you don't really have an answer here, here’s how I do it in JavaScript.
I hope it’s not too hard for you to convert to C#.
// Accepts two hex colors and returns a blended RGB color.

function BlendColors(C1,C2){

var R1=parseInt(C1.substring(1,3),16), G1=parseInt(C1.substring(3,5),16), B1=parseInt(C1.substring(5,7),16);

var R2=parseInt(C2.substring(1,3),16), G2=parseInt(C2.substring(3,5),16), B2=parseInt(C2.substring(5,7),16);

return 'rgb('+Math.round((R1+R2)/2)+','+Math.round((G1+G2)/2)+','+Math.round((B1+B2)/2)+')';}

NB: Alpha channels not taken into consideration.
In theory, all you gotta do is average the three individual components R/G/B.
Update:
Well what do you know... a nice website does language conversions!
using System;

public static string BlendColors(string C1, string C2)
{
    int R1 = Convert.ToInt32(C1.Substring(1, 2), 16);
    int G1 = Convert.ToInt32(C1.Substring(3, 2), 16);
    int B1 = Convert.ToInt32(C1.Substring(5, 2), 16);

    int R2 = Convert.ToInt32(C2.Substring(1, 2), 16);
    int G2 = Convert.ToInt32(C2.Substring(3, 2), 16);
    int B2 = Convert.ToInt32(C2.Substring(5, 2), 16);

    return $"rgb({Math.Round((R1 + R2) / 2.0)},{Math.Round((G1 + G2) / 2.0)},{Math.Round((B1 + B2) / 2.0)})";
}

